# JAX-WS client with Axis service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, axis, jax-rpc

I'm relatively new to web services, but I need to integrate a call to an existing service in my application. Ideally, I'd like to use JAX-WS because I'm looking for the simplest, quickest-to-develop solution on my end, and MyEclipse is able to generate a JAX-WS client from a WSDL. Unfortunately, the WSDL I've inherited was built from what appears to be Axis using RPC. Will this still work? When trying to generate the code, I get these errors, and the web searches I've found seem to say that it's the service end that needs to upgrade:

```
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="impl:MyTypeList[]" />
</restriction>
```

- WS-I: (BP2108) An Array declaration uses - restricts or extends - the soapEnc:Array type, or the wsdl:arrayType attribute is used in the type declaration
- WS-I: (BP2122) A wsdl:types element contained a data type definition that is not an XML schema definition

  > <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  >       namespace="http://ws.host.com" use="encoded" />
- WS-I: (BP2406) The use attribute of a soapbind:body, soapbind:fault, soapbind:header and soapbind:headerfault does not have value of "literal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what version of Axis was used by the service?

Your best bet is to generate a client using the same version of Axis that was used by the service. This is definitely the quickest-to-develop solution.  Using JAX-WS will not work.