# Spring WS Client - How to create mapping POJO for WSDLs without using Axis

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis, spring-ws

I'm creating a Spring WS client. I have a **huge** WSDL from a third-party company. They provide a set of classes that maps to their WSDL via the Axis' WSDL2Java.  I don't want to use Axis or any dependencies from them.

Since this is a web service client, I'm free to choose any framework. My problem is how do I generate a mapping class for the WSDL without using Axis's WSDL2Java. Am I stuck with manipulating pure XML? Take note I'm using Spring WS.

**Edit:**

Is it true if the service provider has built their service with Axis 1, you're basically stuck with making a client that's also based on Axis 1? I read it from this answer [JAX-WS client with Axis service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777118/jax-ws-client-with-axis-service). I thought web services are supposed to be decoupled or at least independent from the platform that it was created, allowing you to have a .Net based web service to be accessed from a Java based client and vice versa?

Comment: By the way, I'm able to access the web service through Soap UI.

Comment: It depends on the style of WSDL. Axis1 *can* generate non-standard WSDL that nothing else can talk to.

Comment: Ahhh...that sucks. How do I know if the WSDL I have is a non-standard WSDL? Soap UI is able to send a message with it.

Comment: @chris: If `wsimport` likes it, then it's OK.

Comment: Thanks skaffman. You're a huge help. Keep it goin' :)

Comment: Example how write simple client and server http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Spring-WS, then your best bet is to use the `wsimport` tool that ships with Java 6 (or use the JAX-WS RI, if you're on Java5). This will generate JAX-WS stubs for the web service.  Included in these stubs will be standard JAXB bindings for the WSDL's schema, and those can be used with Spring-WS (`wsimport` will generate other service stubs that you won't need for Spring-WS).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This gives me a good direction on where to look at :)

Comment: I just tried wsimport from the command line and it created the stubs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in generating the POJOs from the WSDL, I think you could just get the XSD from the WSDL and use XJC tool to generate only the JAXB beans. This would avoid generating useless JAX-WS stubs.