# soap webservice to return a pojo instead of xml

Tags: web-services, soap, axis, spring-ws

I'm quite new to webservices, recently started implementing Soap Webservice using Spring-WS and client using Axis and Spring. As i understood, we send xml as request for webservice and we get back response xml. These request/response Xmls can then be marshalled/unmarshalled.

Is there a way to directly return a pojo from webservice and get it on client side with out xml marshall/unmarshalling?

Comment: Do you mean using native java serialization instead of XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We always end up using Apache Axis and using WSDL2JAVA which produces pojo's for you and hides the service implementation.  For the marshaling you can use something like XMLBeans to easily marshal between xml and pojos.

Also see [Spring WS Client - How to create mapping POJO for WSDLs without using Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344725/spring-ws-client-how-to-create-mapping-pojo-for-wsdls-without-using-axis)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : no.